Embed torsion points in $\mathbb{Q}$ of Elliptic curve into reduction
I am reading Section X.6 'The curve $Y^2=X^3+DX$' in Silverman's elliptic curve book.
The author says: 'Next we recall from (VII $3.5$) that if $p \neq 2 $ and if $E$ has good reduction at $p$, then $E_{tor}(\mathbb{Q})$ injects into the reduction $\tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_p)$".
The problem is that: how can I ensure the group $E(\mathbb{Q})[p]$ injects into the reduction $\tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_p)$? In this case the VII $3.5$ (I think should be VII $3.1$) cannot be applied. Or we need to show $E(\mathbb{Q})[p]$ is trivial. But $p$ is selected in general, not a specific prime number. (If $p$ is chosen to be a speccial number, say $p=3$, then I can embed $E(\mathbb{Q})[3]$ into $\tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_5)$, and count points in $\tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_5)$ by hand.)


It is (VII.3.5) that's used. But (VII.3.5) could use some extra explanation, as noted in the errata sheet, and re-posted here:
[Addendum to (VII.3.5)]
We note that if $E$ has good reduction at $p$, and if $P=(x,y)\in{E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{tors}}}$ is in the kernel of the reduction map $E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{tors}}\to\tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_p)$, then $p$ divides the denominators of $x$ and $y$. But we have just proven that if $P$ has order at least $3$, then $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$. It follows that for all primes $p$ of good reduction, the kernel of the reduction-mod-$p$ map is contained in $E[2]$.  Since we also know from (VII.3.1) that the kernel of the reduction-mod-$p$ map has $p$-power order, we see that the kernel is trivial when $p\ge3$. This proves:
$$
\Bigl(\text{$p\ge3$ and $E$ good reduction at $p$}\Bigr)
\;\Longrightarrow\;
\Bigl(\text{$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{tors}}\hookrightarrow\tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is injective}\Bigr).
$$
